# Can the non-restrictive clause NOT be next to the noun it modifies?

Tags: word-order, syntactic-analysis, relative-clauses

> - The idea was borrowed from finance companies' high-efficiency routine of aligning business processes to achieve optimal growth, which abused the local laws to limit competition.
> - The idea was borrowed from finance companies' high-efficiency routine, which abused the local laws to limit competition, of aligning business processes to achieve optimal growth.

In this sentence the clause "which abused the local laws to limit competition" is supposed to describe "high-efficiency routine."

Are both usages correct?

I am not sure about the second sentence because it uses the descriptive clause "which abused the local laws to limit competition" before the restrictive clause "of aligning business processes to achieve optimal growth"

Comment: In fact, I prefer the second sentence. In the first one, the antecedent of *which* is not clear at all (routine? optimal growth?)

Comment: This question gets off to a bad start by assuming that the non-restrictive relative clause modifies a noun.  In both examples, the relative clauses go next to noun phrases.  McCawley gives a careful account of the constituent structure of relative clauses in **The Syntactic Phenomena of English**.

Answer (score 2):

As Brian says, the first rendering flows better. There is also no real issue with the nonrestrictive clause not directly following what it modifies, because it *does* directly follow what it modifies.

*Of aligning business processes to achieve optimal growth* is not a restrictive clause—it’s not a clause at all, since there is no predicate. It’s a prepositional phrase within a prepositional phrase (or two closely connected parallel prepositional phrases, depending on your viewpoint—I’ll just treat them as one here).

This prepositional phrase is embedded into the larger noun phrase, which in full is *finance companies’ high-efficiency routine of aligning business processes to achieve optimal growth*. Structurally, this is really no different than *the end of the world*: it consists of a definite noun phrase + a prepositional phrase headed off by *of* to show some kind of relationship of possession or belonging.

Since the resulting noun phrase in your example is very long and the prepositional phrase has quite a high level of autonomy, as it were, you can break up the noun phrase by inserting the nonrestrictive relative clause right after the head of the noun phrase without it sounding too odd; in the *end of the world* example, that would be difficult:

> The end of the world, which we all fear, is nigh! *[Perfectly fine]*
>   The end, which we all fear, of the world is nigh! *[Highly awkward at best]*

But just as in the *end of the world* example, you can just as easily keep the nonrestrictive relative clause right after the entire noun phrase, which is what you’ve done in your first rendering.

Answer (score 0):

The first rendering flows better. The second seems to interrupt.  If I used that ordering, I would set off the "which" clause with parentheses rather than commas.